# Issues with arrays in django views

Tags: python, django, arrays, encoding

I am fetching data from database which is stored in arrays, I have to match the output of this array with a string. But array outputs the result into Unicode format  (u'aviesta',) thus it does not match the string.

My code.

```
// fblike is an arry in which the output of query stores.

for i in fblike:
  if i=="Aviesta":
    like=1
return render_to_response('showroom.html')
```

i have also try to encode this as **variable.encode('utf8')** but it only encode the specific element of an array such as i[0].encode('utf8') but i do not know which element of array have aviesta as a value.Thus i need to encode whole array but5 i don't know how to do that.

Updated::
**In views.py is use**

```
cursor = connection.cursor()  
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM django_facebook_facebooklike WHERE user_id = %s", request.user.id)  
rowfb = cursor.fetchall() return render_to_response('showroom.html',{'rowfb':rowfbthis}
```

and **print the {{rowfb}} variable in my template**..and **result** array is

```
 ((u'Mukesh Chapagain',), (u'Ghrix Technologies Private Limited',), (u'FirstLALimo',), (u'Aviesta',), (u'Awkward Group',), (u'FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading',), (u'99recharge',), (u'AllThingsCustomized.com',), (u'celebrity aviesta',), (u'FTC',))
```

So please suggest me some way so that i can match the elements of array with the given string.

Thanks

Comment: Please show show you are fetching the data. I doubt very much it has anything to do with "arrays".

Comment: Why are you not writing `if i == u"Aviesta"` then? Normal strings (byte arrays) are not very good for doing string processing since they are encoded

Comment: @Esailija that has nothing to do with his problem. `"Aviesta" == u"Aviesta"`. But without seeing his alleged "arrays", we'll never know what the actual problem is.

Comment: BUt in Database it's only aviesta.....I am also trying to compare with u'aviesta' ..but not success

Comment: In views.py is use    cursor = connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM django_facebook_facebooklike WHERE user_id = %s", request.user.id)
   rowfb = cursor.fetchall()
   return render_to_response('showroom.html',{'rowfb':rowfbthis}  and print the {{rowfb}} variable in my template..and result array is ((u'Mukesh Chapagain',), (u'Ghrix Technologies Private Limited',), (u'FirstLALimo',), (u'Aviesta',), (u'Awkward Group',), (u'FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading',), (u'99recharge',), (u'AllThingsCustomized.com',), (u'celebrity aviesta',), (u'FTC',))

Comment: @DanielRoseman well I guess it still passes as general advice at least :P

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should have posted the code as an update to your question, rather than a comment.

Secondly, I have no idea why you are accessing the data via a manual SQL query, rather than using Django's ORM. If you had done it the normal way, you would not be having this problem.

Finally, your problem has nothing to do with encodings. Your data is as follows (reposted for clarity):

```
((u'Mukesh Chapagain',), (u'Ghrix Technologies Private Limited',), (u'FirstLALimo',), (u'Aviesta',), (u'Awkward Group',), (u'FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading',), (u'99recharge',), (u'AllThingsCustomized.com',), (u'celebrity aviesta',), (u'FTC',))
```

This is a tuple of tuples. Each row of data is represented by a tuple, and in turn each column within that row is a tuple. In your case, since you're only selecting one column, you have a tuple of single-element tuples. That means, in each iteration of your loop, you have a tuple, not a string.

This would work:

```
for i in fblike:
  if i[0] == "Aviesta":
    like = 1
```

but to be honest, you would be better off going and doing a simple Python tutorial, and then going back to the Django tutorial and learning how to do queries via the ORM.

Comment: *What* is? Django helpfully gives you a full traceback in development mode (with DEBUG on), so just saying "500 error" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question has anything to do with arrays.

If you only need to find if the given string is in your array, you could simply do

```
if "Aviesta" in fblike:
    like+=1
```

Comment: this code should work then I don't think it will matter if its unicode or not, this should return True, I mean the code I wrote above